# Selecting rows in mySQL table by comparing the value to python dictionary

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have 2 databases one in mongoDB and one table in mySQL. I am taking data from mongoDB which is being stored in a dictionary and looks like this-

```
dictionary = {
           "message_code": "12345"
}
```

I want to match this message_code value in the mySQL tables colums called final_code and retrieve table rows which match the message_code. How can I do that?

```
SELECT * 
FROM mysql_table 
WHERE final_code = dictionary.message_code
```

Something like this?

Comment: you have to do it the hard way and just construct sql queries based on the dictionary values. You can use select in (1,2,3,4,5) - for multiple values and then sort out the result in your code in order to limit the number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a string to mysql, not python objects. So you must build that string interpolating the values you want in python, i.e.

```
'SELECT * FROM mysql_table WHERE final_code='+dictionary["message_code"]
```

and pass that string to mysql as query.